# Sharepoint doesn't send email to "Current Item:Created By"

Tags: workflow, email

My sharepoint workflow seems to only send email to "Current Item:(Name of user)":
[image]

instead of the list variable "Created By" as in "Current Item:Created By".
[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

The error sent to my smtp server email is:

> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>   Created By
>   The format of the email address isn't correct. A correct address looks like this: someone@example.com. Please check the recipient's email address and try to resend the message.

But "Created By" is a variable. It shouldn't be in an email format. Also, last I checked, this variable has a name inside. It's not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the picture below I have used the field '**Assigned To**', you have used '**Created By**', but in order for Sharepoint to be able to send an email, it does need an email address.

[image: Workflow image]

If I substitute my **Assigned To** person/group field for the **Created By** field you'll see you can define the field to be used as an email address - select this one in your workflow, republish and save.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you please ensure that the "Created By" field is returned as Email address as shown below:
[image]